# Trying to fetch all running tasks in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch all the currently running apps and i am trying to do it like this:

```
try
{
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
}
catch (SecurityException e)
{
   //Something
}
```

But every time i am trying to run it on emulator it's giving me force close error message.

Comment: sorry thats List class was mistyped in fact i am using : - 
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

Comment: you can format your code putting 4 spaces before each line, or using the `{}` button on top of the editor *(I've done it for you)* -- see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more informations on the syntax you can use when posting on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It need permission to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: @Varundroid: if an answer is helpful for you, please upvote it - this is how StackOverflow members express their thanks here. :)

Comment: i tried but it said you can't upvote it until you have 15 points. :(