# How to know other application is in use from my application

Tags: android

I have a requirement that , I want to do some changes in my application, If some other application ,let say "com.android.abc"  is in use.

Pl. let me know can I get the package names of the currently running apps in my application..?

I can use Broad cast receiver , but I dont have access for the other application to modify it and send some notification to my app.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409804/trying-to-fetch-all-running-tasks-in-android).

If you can't do that (as in, get that permission), then you can't accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks Dhaivat Pandya,  but how to initialize "am".  I think we can't create object for ActvityManager directly, Instead we have to use context.getSystemService(). Can you please tell me which constant I need to pass in getSystemService() method..??